# Select2 drop down change event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, dropdown

I am using **Select2** drop down and I need to do some functionalities based on the the drop down selection.

I have tried the following code, but it didn't worked for me.

```
$eventSelect.on("select2:select", function (e) { log("select2:select", e); });

$eventSelect.on("change", function (e) { log("change"); });
```

Can anyone tell me how can I make this work?

Comment: Did you try to include the function code I included in my answer? What was the error message that you got, if it said 'log is not defined' then it would be due to you not having including the function in your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am using select2 version **3.3.2** and the following code is working for me

```
$("#id").on("change", function () { debugger; });
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try declaring the event after you know the web page has fully loaded, in my case, this was the problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourselect').on("select2:select", function(e) { 
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$eventSelect.select2().on("change", function(e) {
          // mostly used event, fired to the original element when the value changes
          log("change val=" + e.val);
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('change', '.js-example-basic-single', function(e) {
console.log($(this).val());})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you took your code from the select2 documentation:

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic-control

Did you notice that they define a function below that code is using called log().

Here is the function code, did you include that also?

```
function log (name, evt) {
  if (!evt) {
      var args = "{}";
  } else {
      var args = JSON.stringify(evt.params, function (key, value) {
      if (value && value.nodeName) return "[DOM node]";
      if (value instanceof $.Event) return "[$.Event]";
      return value;
      });
  }
  var $e = $("<li>" + name + " -> " + args + "</li>");
  $eventLog.append($e);
  $e.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 10000, 'linear', function () {
      $e.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 2000, 'linear', function () {
          $e.remove();
      });
    });
}
```

Alternatively you could use console.log() to output to the console.

Comment: I am not using the log method still it is not working.

Comment: Your code does use the log function it's called on both lines in your answer. Try including this code in my post on your page. What was the error in the browser?

Comment: Actually I am not using the log method in my code, My code is some thing like this, 
`$eventSelect.on("select2:select", function (e) { debugger; });
$eventSelect.on("change", function (e) { debugger; });`
and there is no error at all , the problem is that the debugger is not hitting when i change the dropdown selection.

Comment: You see how twice in your code it's says log(...) That is calling the log function. There must be a function in your code called log for that to work. Have you tried adding the code in my answer? What is your error message?

Comment: It might have been better to post up all of your actual code, better still if you could include a link to an example. The code you posted is the correct way to check for the select2 events for version 4+ . I know that prior to version 4 the API is very different, although I'm not sure about the events. What version are you using, are you looking at the correct documentation?

Answer (score 0):

With select2 version 4 the events have changed. This is an old version example

```
$('#exampleVersionOld').select2().on('change', function(item){
    ...
});
```

And here is a new version example

```
$('#exampleVersion4').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var item = e.params.data;
});
```

Note the structure of the item also changes with this new event.

Here is a list of all the new events

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

Answer (score 0):

As of version [4.0.0](https://github.com/select2/select2/releases/tag/4.0.0), Can use the following events:

Reference: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

> select2:close
> select2:open
> select2:opening
> select2:selecting
> select2:removed
> select2:unselecting

For Example:

```js
(function($){
  $('.select2').select2();
  
  $('.select2').on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
    console.log('Selecting: ' , e.params.args.data);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>



<select class="select2">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```