# Select2 trigger on click

Tags: javascript, triggers, click, jquery-select2

I have seen many topics about select2 trigger but I can't find a solution to my case.
I want my select2 filter to load some data immediately when a user click on it.

Is that possible ? I tried to do it, it only works when a another option is selected, not at the moment when the select is clicked.

Thanks !

For example, this works for change trigger :

```
$('#id_station').on('select2:select', function (e) {
   alert();
});
```

Comment: what is the problem? as i see on selection of dropdown your alert should be called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 drop down change event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735337/select2-drop-down-change-event-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using select2 version **4.0.3** and the following code is working for me

```
   $('#id_station').on('select2:select', function (e) {
   alert();
});
```

please check below example

```js
(function($){
  $('#id_station').select2();
  
 
  $('#id_station').on('select2:select', function (e) {
   alert("Selected");
});

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.select2{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2" id="id_station">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">Option 6</option>
  <option value="7">Option 7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @AjaxLoser : you should accept and vote up the answer if it helps you, so that others can find it helpful.